# Not able to set the height of the custom Keyboard for using any of the version xcode beta 3, beta 4, beta 5, beta 6

Tags: ios, xcode

This question has appeared at many places but not found the exact solution, i tried including apple provided code in viewWillAppear, viewDidLoad, setNeedsUpdateConstraints but nothing is useful not even with updated beta 6 version below is the code

```
CGFloat _expandedHeight = 500;
NSLayoutConstraint *_heightConstraint = 
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.view 
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight 
                                 relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                    toItem: nil 
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute 
                                multiplier: 0.0 
                                  constant: _expandedHeight];
[self.view addConstraint: _heightConstraint];
```

where exactly i should place the above block of code?

Couldn't attach the present view of keyboard due to low reputation

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423323/ios-8-keyboard-height-and-key-effects**
 i also face same problem

Comment: Perhaps answers to this question will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167909/ios-8-custom-keyboard-changing-the-height