# How to change iOS 8 custom keyboard height with Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, keyboard

I'm making a custom keyboard for iOS 8 using Swift. I'm extremely new to iOS development and I've been unable to solve this problem on my own. In the App Extension Programming documents online Apple said that you can change the height of any custom keyboard after it has been launched. They provided an example in Objective-C but I'm using Swift and so far, I can't seem to find a Swift version of the code.

Can someone convert the 3 lines of code into Swift or show me a way to change the height of the keyboard please?

Here's the webpage with the code:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html

And here's the lines of code:

```
CGFloat _expandedHeight = 500;
NSLayoutConstraint *_heightConstraint = 
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.view 
    attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight 
    relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual 
    toItem: nil 
    attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute 
    multiplier: 0.0 
    constant: _expandedHeight];
[self.view addConstraint: _heightConstraint];
```

Comment: You may want to check out this question for more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167909/ios-8-custom-keyboard-changing-the-height/25819565#25819565

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, 
                                     attribute: .Height, 
                                     relatedBy: .Equal, 
                                        toItem: nil, 
                                     attribute: .NotAnAttribute, 
                                    multiplier: 0.0, 
                                      constant: expandedHeight)
```

Comment: I put the code you gave me into the .swift file for my keyboard and the height doesn't change? Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: That would be a different question, right? Does it work in Objective-C?

Comment: I only tried Swift. But I was putting it in the viewDidLoad method and I just read I show put it in viewDidAppear, I'll try that and let you know the result.

Answer (score 4):

I added the code provided to the viewDidAppear method and the keyboard resized itself.

Here's the code that worked.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let expandedHeight:CGFloat = 500
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item:self.view,
        attribute: .Height,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: nil,
        attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
        multiplier: 0.0,
        constant: expandedHeight)
    self.view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
}
```

Comment: But I got this: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff523267da0 V:[UIInputView:0x7ff520f198a0(700)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff5230dd2b0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIInputView:0x7ff520f198a0(216)]>"
)

Comment: I got an error saying "Could not find member 'Height'"

Comment: @EthanLong this trouble is happen when you set your inputview height shorter. i'm having same trouble right now and can't found anyway to solve it!

Comment: @MoatazHossam yep, finally i've found a solution for it. that you have to set priority for your constraint. just like this: `height.priority = 800` , bOOm! , problem solved!

Comment: so your constraint will not be applied and the keyboard will not be shorter than the native keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

completely,

```
let expandedHeight:CGFloat = 500
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item:self.view,
            attribute: .Height,
            relatedBy: .Equal,
            toItem: nil,
            attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
            multiplier: 0.0,
            constant: expandedHeight)
            self.view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
```

Comment: This just repeats the previous answer with faulty formatting. The question only asked for line 3.

Comment: @Mundi please read question as @Francis asked `Can someone convert the 3 lines of code into Swift` not line 3 and please show me the faults

Comment: OK, thanks for pointing this out. Still not really necessary to reiterate the obvious.