# How can I add an extra tool bar above iOS8 custom keyboard like the picture?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, custom-keyboard

I'm working on iOS8 custom keyboard now. I want to change the height of the keyboard Controller's view, but I failed.On the WWDC 2014, Apple said it maybe can be chaged later. So I really have no idea. Maybe I can add a toolbar like the picture say, but I don't how to do it. I really need you help. Thanks so much!![image]

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26062109/690918

Comment: You may not believe it that the truth is not like what the documentation says. You can see this question on the StackOverflow : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167909/ios-8-custom-keyboard-changing-the-height

Many people tried the method on the documentation, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using an xib to load your view, or are you creating your buttons and view programmatically?