# How to add toolbar above iOS8 custom keyboard?

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

My problem is write picture. I really need you help. Maybe inputAccessoryView, inputAccessoryViwController can be used, but I really have no idea. Thanks so much!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the height of your custom keyboard’s primary view using Auto Layout. By default, a custom keyboard is sized to match the system keyboard, according to screen size and device orientation. A custom keyboard’s width is always set by the system to equal the current screen width. To adjust a custom keyboard’s height, change its primary view's height constraint.

The following code lines show how you might define and add such a constraint:

```
CGFloat _expandedHeight = 500;
NSLayoutConstraint *_heightConstraint = 
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.view 
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight 
                                 relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                    toItem: nil 
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute 
                                multiplier: 0.0 
                                  constant: _expandedHeight];
[self.view addConstraint: _heightConstraint];
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html

Add the code to viewDidAppear/viewWillAppear

Add your bar to the extra space. You can not make the background transparent.

Comment: You may not believe it that the truth is not like what the documentation says. You can see this question on the StackOverflow : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167909/ios-8-custom-keyboard-changing-the-height

Many people tried the method on the documentation, but it doesn't work.

Comment: But SwiftKey obviously got it to work. What the hell did they do? Black magic?

Comment: zeiteisen is right - add the constraints to ViewDidAppear/ViewWillAppear, not ViewDidLoad