# Increase height of custom keyboard iOS 8 not working

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8

I tried to increase height of custom keyboard using Apple's doc but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    CGFloat _expandedHeight = 500;
    NSLayoutConstraint *_heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                        multiplier:0.0 constant: _expandedHeight];
    [self.view addConstraint: _heightConstraint];
    [super updateViewConstraints];

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 8 Custom Keyboard: Changing the Height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167909/ios-8-custom-keyboard-changing-the-height)