# Custom keyboard with native prediction in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, keyboard, ios-app-extension

The goal: to create a custom keyboard for Russian lang with QuickType (Predictive) which should look like native (I can't post image because of small reputation but I guess it's clear to understand) with some changes: own algorithm to show words; user can chose from more than 3 options

I've found out that it can not be done by standart features (like "set some property like quickType to YES"), but may be exists some another way to do it? e.g. create custom view or smth like that, so the question is:

Can I do so by custom view (with height greater than "215 +/- px") or is there some other way? And will Apple take it then?

**UPD** It's important that custom looks exactly as native.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your custom word completion view as a sub view of the keyboard (the same way you add the buttons for your keys). Of course you will need to increase the height of the keyboard in order to provide the additional height for your completion view.

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html)

> You can adjust the height of your custom keyboard’s primary view using Auto Layout. By default, a custom keyboard is sized to match the system keyboard, according to screen size and device orientation. A custom keyboard’s width is always set by the system to equal the current screen width. To adjust a custom keyboard’s height, change its primary view's height constraint.

You can also find a code sample on that page. I see no reason Apple will reject based on what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the height is possible. Check out this question [iOS 8 Custom Keyboard: Changing the Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167909/ios-8-custom-keyboard-changing-the-height/25819565?noredirect=1#comment42988112_25819565)

You can provide a custom view to show prediction. 'Touchpal' in the App Store may be helpful for you. The 'Touchpal' English keyboard has some QuickType features just like system keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom keyboard look and feel and your predictive mechanics (QuickType like) are all your responsibilities. There is no way to just copy or enable something. You should just program another absolutely the same keyboard from scratch and another QuickType-like algorithm. iOS8 just provides you with empty view that you can change height for.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `UILexicon` object and especially at the `UITextChecker`:

```
UITextChecker *checker = [[UITextChecker alloc] init];
NSRange checkRange = NSMakeRange(0, text.length);
NSRange misspelledRange = [checker rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:text 
                                                           range:checkRange
                                                      startingAt:checkRange.location
                                                            wrap:NO 
                                                        language:@"en_US"];
NSArray *arrayCorrected = [checker guessesForWordRange:misspelledRange 
                                              inString:text 
                                              language:@"en_US"];
return [arrayCorrected objectAtIndex:0];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextChecker_Class/index.html

Comment: UITextChecker doesn't work correctly with Russian and UILexicon is used for get user's data from iPhone (such as address, names etc)