# Customize customKeyboard height after loading the view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, custom-keyboard

I'm coding a custom keyboard and i want to customize the height.. 
Apple Documentation give that code only in Objective-C, does anyone know how to write it in Swift Language? This is the code from Apple:

```
CGFloat _expandedHeight = 500;
NSLayoutConstraint *_heightConstraint = 
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.view 
                             attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight 
                             relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                toItem: nil 
                             attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute 
                            multiplier: 0.0 
                              constant: _expandedHeight];
[self.view addConstraint: _heightConstraint];
```

I tried to write it like this but it doesn't do anything..:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated:Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

   let nib = UINib(nibName: "KeyboardView", bundle: nil)
    let objects = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)
    view = objects[0] as UIView;

    let _viewHeight: CGFloat = 256

    let const1 = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item:self.view, attribute:.Height,
        relatedBy:.Equal, toItem:nil,
        attribute:.NotAnAttribute,multiplier:0, constant: _viewHeight)

    view.addConstraint(const1)

 }
```

Help me please!

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167909/ios-8-custom-keyboard-changing-the-height/25819565#25819565

Answer (score 1):

You have a `multiplier:0`, it should be `multiplier:1.0`.

You might also mixed `self.view` and `view = objects[0] as UIView`. You should add a constraint to your main `self.view` which is = `self.inputView` and add your custom view on it.

```
let customView = objects[0] as UIView
customView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
self.view.addSubView(customView)

//layout
let left = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
let right = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
let bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
self.view.addConstraints([left, top, right, bottom])

let const1 = NSLayoutConstraint(
    item:self.view, attribute:.Height,
    relatedBy:.Equal, toItem:nil,
    attribute:.NotAnAttribute,multiplier:1.0, constant: _viewHeight)
self.view.addConstraint(const1)
```