# UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width / Height Constrained to Zero

Tags: uitableview, autolayout

There are a number of stack overflow questions about auto-layout of `UITableView` cells and section headers / footers that concern the `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width` constraints that the `UITableView` uses to make its components be the correct size:

- [what is NSLayoutConstraint "UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height" and how should I go about forcing it to recalculate cleanly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25059443/2547229)
- [iOS 8.3 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' in Custom Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29565284/2547229)
- [Auto-layout: What creates constraints named UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width & Height?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23308400/2547229)
- [What is a 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21161765/2547229)

The purpose of these constraints seems pretty clear – they allow the `UITableView` and also `UICollectionView` to interface with constraint layout and pass in its specification about how large cells (and other components) should be.

Most issues seem to be that people have a set of **required** constraints that are incompatible with these encapsulation constraints also requiring a size of `0`. The most workable answers seem to be to lower the priority of user defined constraints to `999` so that the framework's can overrule them.

However – what I'm interested in understanding is *why* is `UITableView` requiring a width of `0` for one of its views? **Is this a bug? Or is it a results of incorrect use? Or does it make perfect sense?**

Height constraints of `0` sometimes make sense, if cells are being expanded from nothing. Lowering priorities is a good way to handle this. But why would the cells be getting a **width** of `0`?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, I didn't, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

UIView doesn't have the intrinsic size hence width and height constraints needed.
**UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width** and **UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height** are created by UICollectionView / UITableView initially. And later on sets the constraint constant based to the sizeForItem or heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method. To ensure that UICollectionViewCell / UITableViewCell created in cellForItem / cellForRow method will be having the exact size.

Comment: Hence i think it is making the perfect sense. :)