# iOS 8 Custom Keyboard: issues when changing default keyboard height

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, keyboard

Having implemented a similar method described in [iOS 8 Custom Keyboard: Changing the Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167909/ios-8-custom-keyboard-changing-the-height), I have two main issues that I can't seem to figure out.

1) When a rotation occurs, there is a terribly noticeable jump.  The keyboard rotates at its current height, and then only after the rotation has completed does it abruptly jump to the new height.

2) The contents of the keyboard don't seem to be drawn until the rotation is complete.  This is causing a whole list of problems when trying to use the various available callbacks.  For example, I'm trying to set the contentSize height of my scrollView, which is at the bottom of my keyboard (similar to the old emoji keyboard), to the same height as my scrollView.  However,

```
scrollView.contentSize = scrollView.frame.size.height
```

does not work because the scrollView (nor its enclosing view - tried that also) hasn't reached its final bounds yet.  I've verified this by checking the bounds after the keyboard is completely loaded - only then does the scrollView return the correct value for its height.

The same thing occurs when I try to set the size for the contents of my collectionView (which comprises the main body of the keyboard):

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let heightPortrait: CGFloat = 0.8
    let heightLandscape: CGFloat = 0.8
    var collectionViewHeight = collectionView.bounds.size.height
    var portrait = collectionViewHeight * heightPortrait
    var landscape = collectionViewHeight * heightLandscape
    var newDimensions: CGFloat

    newDimensions = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width < UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height ? portrait : landscape

    return CGSize(width: newDimensions, height: newDimensions)
}
```

I've implemented viewWillTransitionToSize as well so each object will update on rotation, but when it's called, the bounds are once again not yet set:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    self.setKeyboardHeight() // Change the keyboard height from its default setting.
    self.buildScrollView() // Populate the scrollView and set contentSize as well as cell attributes.

    println("Before: \(self.view4.frame.size.height)") // Is the same as 'After' (see a few lines below), also swapping out view4 (the scrollView's superview) for scrollView doesn't change anything.

    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(nil, completion: { context in
        self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()

        println("After: \(self.view4.frame.size.height)")

    })
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
}
```

I've been cracking my head over this for way too long, so if anyone can help me figure it out I will be eternally grateful.  Thank you so much for your help and any time you may take to answer/work on this!!