# Set custom keyboard height in iOS9 public beta

Tags: ios, keyboard

I am working on a custom keyboard. It works fine on iOS8, but then ios9 public beta was released and updated my phone to ios9. My keyboard is not a traditional keyboard and so it doesn't need all that space, so I was using the height constraint as mentioned here:
[iOS 8 Custom Keyboard: Changing the Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167909/ios-8-custom-keyboard-changing-the-height/25819565#25819565)

and also on the apple's official custom keyboard page here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html

However none of these work in ios9 any more. Forums at developer.apple.com are of no help and I have no ideas any more except to believe that this is either a bug or apple has removed this functionality.

Has any one else noticed this ?

Comment: Still not working though...

Answer (score 2):

Change the height of the keyboard in viewDidAppear with a different value from the initial value.

```
Height+=1;
[self.inputView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
```