# Need Help on Custom Keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, ios-app-extension

I make a custom keyboard, this one [GitHub of My First Custom Keyboard](https://github.com/Rombond/Custom-Keyboard):

[image]

but it looks so tight.
I have searched a method to make it bigger and i found that

```
var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func updateViewConstraints() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()
    let customHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2

    if heightConstraint == nil {
        heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view,
                                              attribute: .height,
                                              relatedBy: .equal,
                                              toItem: nil,
                                              attribute: .notAnAttribute,
                                              multiplier: 1,
                                              constant: customHeight)
        heightConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(UILayoutPriorityRequired)
        print("Setuped")
        view.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
    }
    else {
        print("2")
        heightConstraint.constant = customHeight
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work on my custom keyboard, nothing happens so i have downloaded a bigger custom keyboard made from this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167909/ios-8-custom-keyboard-changing-the-height)
Link: [GitHub of Downloaded Keyboard](https://github.com/yichizhang/CustomHeightKeyboard):

[image]

This keyboard have a perfect height but when i add a button he doesn't work anymore :/ [GitHub of Edited by me Downloaded Keyboard](https://github.com/Rombond/Downloaded-Edited-Keyboard)
So if someone can make my first custom keyboard taller or add a button on the downloaded keyboard, it will be kind

Comment: For the custom keyboard view, try setting  translatesAutoResizingMaskToConstraints = NO.

Comment: @Brandon nothing happens too :/

Answer (score 0):

What is it doing if you change the `toItem: nil` to the top superView ?