# Is it possible to decrease the height of the keyboard without auto layout in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, keyboard

I need to decrease the height of the keyboard programatically. Is there any way I can do it? I have found that we can reduce height, using keyboard extensions but I tried and it doesn't work for me.

Is there any way I can do this?

Edit: But i can see small keyboards in some of the apps . How do they acheive it.
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The screenshot you provided does not show a keyboard with a small size, it's regular-sized AFAIK.

Comment: Please check the following link [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167909/ios-8-custom-keyboard-changing-the-height)

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot modify** the frame or the look of the keyboard, since it works kind of like an overlay over your app and it's not a direct subview in the window where your app lives.

You can create a custom keyboard for this approach, but remember to follow [the iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/extensions/custom-keyboards/).

You can also create a custom view that provides input (for e.g. a bunch `UIButton`s that append a letter to a `UITextView` if you press them).

Comment: Please check my Edited question. I can see some of the keyboards with small size. how is it possible?

Comment: currently my app keyboard height is 260.0