# How Decrease the Keyboard height

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

Please help me.I am new to IOS Swift.I want to decrease the `Height of keyboard` for my IOS app. I tried so many of then but nothing has changed.Kindly please help me.

Comment: You cannot modify the height of the system keyboard. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48684686/3151675

Comment: thank you sir. I have tried custom keyboards also but its showing me the default keyboard

Answer (score 1):

You can not **modify** the height of default Keyboard of iPhone.
The possible solution is to use Custom Keyboard, There are a lot pods available for this.

Comment: can you please mention any suitable pod name?

Comment: thank you sir please suggest some of them